# Working sample code for button.performClick()

Tags: android, button, buttonclick, android-mediarecorder

Can someone please put a working code example of `button.performClick()` assigned to a `OnClickListener`. The following code which I have used returns false for `button.performClick()`-

```
myButton.performClick()
 myButton.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener()
      {
           @Override
           public void onClick ( View view )
           {
              .............
           }
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [button.performclick() is not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16580658/button-performclick-is-not-working)

Comment: what exactly do u want?

Comment: you probably, like, want to add the listener **before** sending events to the button...

Comment: @MehulJoisar actually i want to programatically trigger myButton

Comment: @Raghunandan i did not understand what u meant...

Comment: @monu: can u post your xml and java file ?because we really don't understand what you are asking for.

Answer (score 6):

```
button.performClick()
```

should be `myButton.performClick();` then you should exec it after you register the `OnClickListener`  for your `myButton`

```
myButton.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener()
      {
           @Override
           public void onClick ( View view )
           {
              .............
           }
});


myButton.performClick();
```

Comment: thnku.. actually i am using myButton only.. I have updated my question. the problem is still there..

Comment: you should change the order in which you call setOnClickListener and performClick. See my edit

Comment: and how it stopped ? is myButton null?

Answer (score 1):

Declare the button `Button bmi;`

```
exampleButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

exampleButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
         {public void onClick
         (View  v) { 
             Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), exampleActivity.class);
             startActivity(i);}
         });
```

Let me know if it helped you ;)

Comment: Well this code works, actually i want to programatically trigger exampleButton. For this I have used exampleButton.performClick() which actually returns value false and hence causes no effect..

Answer (score 1):

```
 final Button button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //TODO handle click
            }
        });

        button.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                button.performClick();
            }
        });
```