# Android - Automatically press search button once TextView has input

Tags: android, button, autocomplete, nfc

I have created an app where the user can enter some text and it searches the database once the user presses the search button. I have now modified this so it works with NFC. The NFC tags stores some text (Hello World) and once the tag has been tapped on the phone the text (Hello World) is inserted into the textview. The user can then press the search button and so on.

Is it possible to automatically press the search button once text has been entered into the textbox. For Example, The user taps their phone on the NFC tag, Hello World is entered in the textbox and the search occurs automatically without the user having to press the button.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When user taps their phone on the NFC tag, enter *Hello World* in the textbox and programmatically click SearchButton using `performClick()`.

```
button.performClick();
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I researched perform.Click() and found this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16587549/working-sample-code-for-button-performclick
Appreciate the guidance.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be by using textwatcher on editext.

```
SerachEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {

                if(s.toString().contains("HelloWord Or You unique NFC Text")){

                  //Enter here Button Pressed Code

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                    int arg2, int arg3) {

            }

        });
```

Comment: you can write your own logic for that like whenever tap happens store nfc tag(Hello word) with a key or something. May be this logic in not perfect but Currently I have this one in mind  right now.